# How to create/print DataMatrix barcodes from .NET

Tags: c#, barcode

I want to create DataMatrix ECC200 barcodes from a c# program. Is there a documentation how to encode the information into the barcode, or are there 3rd party assemblies to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [iec16022sharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/iec16022sharp/)?   It hasn't been updated in a few years, but I downloaded it and the code is straightforward and seems to generate good barcodes.